How do I extract a value from a JSON Request and pass it along as header with Nginx?
I have a client application that consumes an service API. The back-end has more than 1 server and I use Nginx for session affinity. The client application does implement the cookie in the header that Nginx requires to persist the session.
I have no control of the client application or the back-end service.
I looking for a way to use Nginx to extract a value from the JSON request and pass it as a header to the back-end in every request. I do not need to modify the payload. Just extract one value from the request and pass it along.
Is it possible to achieve that with only Nginx?
Thank you.

Only using the external modules. Probably the njs module is best suited for this task. Answered you here.
